# Blog Post slider not working

Tags: posts, javascript, blog

I've been trying to create my own slider for my blog posts recently but I cannot get it to work. I have tried different code online but none of them rotate my list items(These are created by the post loop). Below is code I tried from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr) but it shows an error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at carousel**

Here is my function from functions.php which I call on index.php to display the posts:

```
function displayBlogSlider() {

$args = array(

    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="slider js--slider">

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <ul class="slider-inner js--slider-inner">
        <!-- the loop -->

            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="slider-item js--slider-item">
                    <div class="slider-info">    

                            <?php blog_set_featured_background(); ?>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p>By <a href="<?php the_author(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>
                            <p><?php the_date(); ?> &mdash; <a href="#"><?php comments_number(); ?></a> &#9679; <a href="#"><?php the_category(); ?></a></p>

                    </div>
               </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>


        </ul>

        <!-- end of the loop -->
            <div class="slider-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-prev js--nav-prev">&lt;</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-next js--nav-next">&gt;</a>
            </div>

    </div>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif;
}

function blog_set_featured_background() {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), full, false );
    if ($image_url[0]) {
    ?>
        <style>

        .slider-inner {
            height:100%;
            margin:0!important;
        }
        .slider-inner {
            background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80)), url(<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>) #000 no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;

        }
        </style>
 <?php
 }
}
```

And here is my javascript for making the list items rotate(similar to W3S):

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("js--slider-item");

    for(i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        listItem[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    myIndex++;

    if(myIndex > listItem.length) {
        myIndex = 1;
    }

    listItem[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
}
```

If there is a better way of making a carousel for wordpress blog posts, I'll accept all advice and info. **But** I want to create it myself, I don't want to make use of a plugin. Also, I'd prefer pure javascript since I am still learning it.

I want to create something similar to the first slider here - https://manohara.incredibbble.com/

Comment: where are you using the class inner-slider?

Comment: @inarilo sorry, I forgot to change that too. I updated it to **.slider-inner**

Comment: @inarilo I found that if I add the javascript directly in the **index.php** right under the function call for the list of posts, it works! So how do I get the javascript to be read after the function without having to code it directly in the **index.php** but rather link it via **functions.php**?

Comment: adding it to the footer should work

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use `.css("display","none")` instead of `.style.display = "none"`?

So that it looks like this:

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
var i;
var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("js--slider-item");

for(i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    listItem[i].css("display", "none");
}

myIndex++;

if(myIndex > listItem.length) {
    myIndex = 1;
}

listItem[myIndex-1].css("display", "block");
setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
```

}

And what do you get, if you console.log() you're `listItem[i]`?

**EDIT:**

My bad, .css() is, of course, jQuery.

Comment: isn't `css` a jquery functiion?

Comment: @inarilo Yes it is. Early mornin - didn't even notice it was JS. My bad.

Comment: @Kucko, if I console log `listItem[i]` I get error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: listItem is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13**

Comment: Okay - listItem is undefined then. Do you get anything if you console.log listItem variable like this: `var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("js--slider-item");
console.log('List Item = ' + listItem);`

Comment: @Kucko I get the same error. I don't know why it is undefined. Even if I set the javascript to be in the footer to read after everything it still doesn't work. I can upload the theme files to github if that would help?

Comment: @Feyt That would make it a lot easier to debug atleast. Post the link, and I will see what I can do to help :)

Comment: @Kucko here is the link - https://github.com/FullNoob/blogtheme

Answer (score 0):

The slider is probably working but only showing the last image because you are repeatedly defining (and thus overwriting) the same class `slider-inner`. In addition, you are assigning the class, and thus the image, to the list, instead of each list item. Instead define the classes once (ideally in a css file) and use an id to identify each slide:

CSS:

```
.slider-inner {
    height:100%;
    margin:0!important;
}
.slider-item {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For each list item:

```
<li id="slider-item-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="slider-item js--slider-item">...</li>
```

To add images:

```
function blog_set_featured_background() {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), full, false );
    if ($image_url[0]) {
    ?>
        <style>

        #slider-item-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> {
            background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80)), url(<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>) #000 no-repeat;
        }

        </style>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. I will update it to assign the background image to the **li** element. But the biggest problem is still there - the posts don't rotate. I see the same text. Please see the code at [link](https://github.com/FullNoob/blogtheme)

Comment: Also, I used **the_ID()** instead of **$post->ID** for the li elements otherwise it doesn't work